# Failed to load PDF document while downloading crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[image]

Please solve our issue anybody!

We are running code in windows 10, crystal reports are successfully downloaded while running in IIS server, but an error is arising like this:

> Failed to load PDF document.

Please help.

Comment: Are you able to find downloaded `PDF` file. Try opening `PDF` in `Notepad`. In case if error occur while downloading, error message is written in downloaded file; that makes it invalid file. By opening it in `Notepad`, you may get details of error.

Comment: my OS is windows 8.1 , visual studio 2010 and dot net frame work 4   i installed crystal report for Vs 2010 but when opening crystal report in pdf through iis server it is showing error "Failed to load pdf document"

Comment: https://www.sap.com/documents/2015/07/183d21e5-597c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html